# Maximum Principle for holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we know the Maximum Principle for harmonic functions.How can we deduce maximum principle for holomorphic functions from it?

I tried considering exp(f) where f is the concerned holomorphic function but could not proceed any further.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is holomorphic, then $\ln|f|$ is harmonic. Apply harmonic maximum principle to $\ln|f|$.